Using PSSession to Iterate Through a List of Virtual Machines and Resize the Hard Disk to Newly Allocated Disk Space
I'm not new to PowerShell but I'm not fluent with it either so I post my problem here for possible assistance.
I am logged into Windows PowerShell ISE as an admin and I have the PowerCLI module installed and I'm current logged into the Hyper V server that hosts our virtual machines. I have a PS script that will iterate though multiple VM's and expand the disk space on them to achieve 30GB free space. However, I have been having to resize those drives to the newly allocated space one machine at a time using PSSession. I have been looking for a way to use PS script to iterate through a text file list of those machines and resize them just as the other script does for expanding the drives. After some research I realized I could use PSSession to do just that. I created a script to do that and it works fine until it gets to the resize portion of the script below.
Resize-Partition -DriveLetter $drive_letter -Size $size.SizeMax

I get the error message "Resize-Partition : Size Not Supported Extended information:
The partition is already the requested size." I check the test machines and the extended volume is correctly extended but the partition has not been resized to the make the newly provided amount of free disk space. The script is posted below. The full error message I receive will be posted below the script.
I'm not sure what I'm missing here and all assistance provided is appreciated.
Script:
$vmcomputers = Get-Content -Path C:\Temp\computers.txt
$drive_letter = "C"

# iterate through list
$result = foreach ($vmcomputer in $vmcomputers) {
  # create PSsession
  #$session = New-PSSession -ConnectionUri $vmcomputer.hostname
  $session = Get-Content C:\Temp\computers.txt | New-PSSession -ThrottleLimit 50
  
  # resize disk
  $size = (Get-PartitionSupportedSize -DriveLetter $drive_letter)
  Resize-Partition -DriveLetter $drive_letter -Size $size.SizeMax

  # cleanup
  Remove-PSSession -PSSession $session
}

Error message:
Resize-Partition : Size Not Supported
 
Extended information:
The partition is already the requested size.
 
Activity ID: {69684292-964a-4637-92bd-1ddf1ccb773f}
At C:\Temp\ResizeVMdiskPsession\AICodeResizeVmHardDisk.ps1:12 char:3
+   Resize-Partition -DriveLetter $drive_letter -Size $size.SizeMax
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (StorageWMI:ROOT/Microsoft/.../MSF 
   T_Partition) [Resize-Partition], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : StorageWMI 4097,Resize-Partition
 
Remove-PSSession : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 
'PSSession'.
At C:\Temp\ResizeVMdiskPsession\AICodeResizeVmHardDisk.ps1:15 char:20
+   Remove-PSSession -PSSession $session
+                    ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Remove-PSSession], Paramet 
   erBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Comm 
   ands.RemovePSSessionCommand


There are two steps to increase the size of a partition within a Windows VM. You have to increase the size of the VHDD, then within the OS running on the VM, you have to increase the size of one of the partitions on the VHDD. Which step are you trying to script? You seem to have some syntax issues with Remove-PSSession

@Ramhound I'm trying to increase the size of one of the partitions on the VHDD.

@Cpt.Whale Please explain why the script you provided isn't accessing the listed machines from the invoke command as you said it would. Additionally, when running the code in the ISE, the invoke command is never touched at all.

Your ping will never reach Cap.Whale since they didn't submit a comment under your question.

@Ramhound thank you for clarifying what I was already strongly suspecting.

To run commands remotely via PSSession, use Invoke-Command:
# assumes you have a CSV with a hostname column
$vmcomputers = Import-CSV -Path 'C:\Temp\computers.csv'

# iterate through machines
foreach ($vmcomputer in $vmcomputers.hostname) { 
  Invoke-Command -ComputerName $vmcomputer -ScriptBlock {
    # resize partitions
    $drive_letter = "C"
    $size = Get-PartitionSupportedSize -DriveLetter $drive_letter
    Resize-Partition -DriveLetter $drive_letter -Size $size.SizeMax
  }
}


Alternatively, you can use $session = New-PSSession $vmcomputer to create the session, then use it later with Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {...}, but I would only do this if you want to re-use a session multiple times in a script.
Using -ComputerName like in my example just skips the steps of creating/removing PSSessions

I ran this in debug mode for testing and set a breakpoint on the foreach statement, line 5 only. I also set a break point on line 10 for the resize-partition command. I checked the name of the computer it was referencing and it correctly held that machine name. When I manually iterate through each step of the script pressing F11 the script finishes and does not even touch the breakpoint on line 10. This indicates to me that the script isn't even accessing the assigned machine to do complete any other command.

This script does not appear to be functional.  Non-functional scripts are not helpful to the community.

@webby68 we do not vandalize posts just because they are unhelpful. You don't know why Cpt.Whale has not replied yet. This is a site maintained by volunteers and regular folks. Be patient, and use the tools available (votes and comments) to convey your feedback.

@music2myear please explain how I vandalized a post

You submitted an edit to this answer removing all their words and replacing it with this: "The answer given was not helpful and was not an answer at all. It was only an example submitted by someone and the person has not responded to my question about why it doesn't work like he said it would." That is vandalization. Please just stick to the comments and vote buttons going forward. It is the best way to get the most from this site.

@music2myear thank you for your input. It's funny how you see that when I have a notice that says "It is only visible to you until it’s been approved by trusted community members." So if other users can't see it then it isn't vandalization and if it's not approved then it would never be seen at all. So I didn't vandalize. I made a suggested edit that is only supposed to be seen by those who approve it. There was no intention to "vandalize".

I am one of the "trusted community members". You can see in the Help section the reputation required in order to work the review queues. We take suggested edits as intent, eg, you believe the post is better/improved/corrected in the way you are editing it. It isn't a feedback mechanism or a way to reply. It undoes the effort, even misguided, that someone else put into writing what they hoped would be a good answer. The most likely issue here is that there is a small syntax error in the code provided. Mistakes are normal. Grace and patience is the best way.

@music2myear I agree with you. However, if this was a suggested edit that wasn't supposed to be visible to the community and wouldn't be available to the community if it had not been approved, is it really appropriate for you to address me in public about this and make my suggested edit public when it was obviously intended not to be public unless published? I consider this very inappropriate for you to do and the better way to address something like this is in a private mode as was intended from the very beginning when the edit wasn't even made public.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@webby68 The script assumes you have that list of computer hostnames as a CSV with a hostname column (because the code in your question looks for a .hostname property). If your list is formatted differently or missing, the script block won't do anything, because the list of computers to do it on is empty

@webby68 - Your proposal is public here. Your proposal could fit the description of vandalism which is the reason it was rejected by the community. For your information, edit proposals are fully public provided you look at the edit proposal in the queue.
